# Update custom field in Salesforce internally and externally

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, in Account component, I have a custom field called 'Timestamp'. This field is used for synchronization purposes with an external application. I need to achieve below scenarios with this field.

1. The field can be updated via Salesforce API. Here the field is updated with the external timestamp value (Now the 'Timestamp' value is different from 'Last Modified Time' in Salesforce).
2. If any Account related information is updated from Salesforce itself, then the field is updated with current time (Ideally equivalent to 'Last Modified Time' in Salesforce).

I tried Salesforce workflow rules for this but it only achieves the second scenario. For the first scenario it again updates the value with current time instead of the externally recieved value.

How to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the data type of your field Timestamp? I'm guessing it's DateTime if it is DateTime then you could put the value of System.Now() while using from API code and you can write a trigger on account (before update or after update) according to your requirement updating your field with System.Now().

Comment: Yes the data type is Datetime. If I write a trigger on Account update (whether it is before or after) and set the value to System.Now(), isn't it again updated with the current time for both above scenarios? When data is synchronized from external source, I need to update the field with that external timestamp. But when the update is from Salesforce itself, then System.Now() should be set. According to your solution it seems again it's System.Now() time for both cases. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok, then you can use Trigger.old and Trigger.New approach here. When you will update the field via external source your Trigger.new and Trigger.old values will be different and you have not to do any changes, but when it was not via external source your Trigger.old and Trigger.new value will be same and then you can update it with System.Now().